# infinite loop while saving a record in mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am making a POST request to an API which creates a new message and once it is created, in the promise callback, I am saving the message inside user collection as well.

> See this line - user.messages.push(result);     //problem here

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.query.token);
    User.findById(decoded.user._id, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occured',
                error: err
            });
        }
        var message = new Message({
            content : req.body.content,
            user : user      //add the user to messages as a link
        });
        message.save(function(err, result) {
            if(err){
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'An error occured',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            user.messages.push(result);     //problem here 
            user.save();
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Saved message',
                obj: result
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The message is created in message collection but as soon as the highlighted line is reached, the server runs into an infinite loop and stops.

Here is the error the server shows:

[image]

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the push. Are you calling a recursive function elsewhere

Comment: No, I am not using explicit recursion anywhere.

Comment: Well try to write a minimal code to call the API and add functions step by step until you reach the hang. Because there is nothing in this code that can cause your error.

Comment: Solution found.

Comment: was it in this part of code ?

Answer (score 0):

> See this line - user.messages.push(result); //problem here

The result contained the full `user` object instead of `userId` which was supposed to be saved in messages.

The `user` object is structured like this

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5a570976d911c65410b93dc9"), "firstName" : "Rachit", "lastName" : "Garg", "password" : "$2a$10$24G4Gii0s5ityhtTkeK1m.8C2tPJIyKFbsnMSHCtcWkwz85kmr6iS", "email" : "rachigarg@gmail.com", "messages" : [ ObjectId("5a57099dd911c65410b93dcb") ], "__v" : 35 }
```

The `message` object is structured like this.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a57099dd911c65410b93dcb"), "content" : "one more edits", "user" : ObjectId("5a570976d911c65410b93dc9"), "__v" : 0 }
```

The `user` should contain the array of `messageIds` created by user.

The `message` should contain only the `userId` who created the message.

Since the result contained the whole `user` object again and not the `userId` only, it caused an infinite loop.

Here is the fix:

> user.messages.push(result_id); //problem fixed